# Finding the value of stoichiometric coefficient x

Tags: equilibrium

$\ce{2A_{(s)} + xB_{(g)} <=> 3C_{(g)}}$

$\mathrm{K_p}=19.3, \mathrm{K_c}=0.45, \mathrm T=523\pu K$

I work $\Delta n$ to be $1$, So would $x$ be $1$ or $2$? I'm not sure if the coefficient is part of $\Delta n$.

Answer (score 3):

The relationship between $K_p$ and $K_c$ is

$$K_p=K_c(RT)^{\Delta n}$$

where $\Delta n$ is the change in the number of moles of gas molecules over the course of the reaction. The only way you could know this change is from the stoichiometric coefficients. The $\Delta n$ term derives from the laws of mass action in which all partial pressures and/or concentrations are raised to the stoichiometric coefficients.

Consider:

$$\ce{2NO(g) + O2(g) <=> 2NO2(g)}$$
$$K_c = \dfrac{[\ce{NO2}]^2}{[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]}$$
$$K_p = \dfrac{P^2_{\ce{NO2}}}{P^2_{\ce{NO}}P_{\ce{O2}}}$$
$$P_x = \dfrac{n_x}{V_x}RT=[\ce{X}]RT$$
$$K_p = \dfrac{([\ce{NO2}]RT)^2}{([\ce{NO}]RT)^2([\ce{O2}]RT)}$$
$$K_p = \dfrac{[\ce{NO2}]^2}{[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]}\dfrac{(RT)^2}{(RT)^3}=K_c(RT)^{-1}$$
$$\Delta n = -1 =2-(2+1)$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error it seems to make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you calculated $\Delta n$ correctly, the value of $x$ would  be 2, because $\Delta n= 3 - x$.  You only count the coefficients of gases in determining $\Delta n$.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that was the main thing i was confused about, though I did make an error in calculating the delta n Value.